# How to create EmberJS app and stick it into Chrome

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a basic Ember app to then stick into a Chrome extension. I want the Chrome extension to takeover the `newtab` functionality. The end goal is to see the Ember Welcome App whenever I open a new tab.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "geolocation"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-2.2.4.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon.png"
    }
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": { "newtab": "index.html" }
}
```

I am running Ember CLI 3.10 and this is a fresh EmberJS app. I ran `ember build --environment production` and copied over the dist folder into my `chrome` folder that contains my `manifest.json`. I'm referencing my built `index.html` file in my `manifest.json`. The problem I'm running into is that when I open a new page, I get `UnrecognizedURLError: /index.html` that originates from my fingerprinted `vendor.js`. Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: I see several answers when googling for `UnrecognizedURLError`.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://envoy.engineering/a-framework-for-ambitious-chrome-extensions-b08d1f4b944d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I needed to set `locationType` to `'none'` in my `config/environment.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-project',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'none', // changed from 'auto'
    …
  }
```

The idea was to [disable URL management](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_disabling-url-management).